# When styling a Tumblr theme, is {TagsAsClasses} truly the best way to style posts differently, based on what tags it has?

Tags: tumblr

A [developer here](http://themes.pouretrebelle.com/tutorial/) says it could mess up the intended styling if someone chose to tag your post with something else. the workaround that they gave seems unnecessarily complicated. Do you agree with this person's point of view? Is there anything else you might suggest?

Answer (score 3):

**Styling with Tags**

Sadly the documentation for `TagsAsClasses` is a little incomplete, but clarified [here](http://staff.tumblr.com/post/166789387/tag-tip-for-theme-designers):

> If you’re using `{TagsAsClasses}` to apply special formatting to posts with certain tags, you might not want those particular tags showing up on your blog or on the Dashboard.  Luckily, tags prefixed with an underscore, like *_promo*, will only appear in `{TagsAsClasses}` (with the underscore removed).

This can still cause issues as the prefix `_` is removed on render, `_promo` becomes `promo`. If the user tags a post `promo` it will unintentionally invoke the style.

**Double Up!**

The simplest solution would be to double prefix any tags used for styling purposes. `__promo` becomes `_promo`. You can then style `._promo` as you see fit.

Comment: Wow, didn't even know about this. I've been hiding classes with css like `.tags a[href*='promo']` but of course they still appear in other parts on Tumblr